# C# VSTO in Powerpoint, chart with dynamic updating data fails screenshot

Tags: c#, graph, vsto, powerpoint, screenshot

I have a VSTO that updates data inside a graph in a powerpoint presentation. but when i take a screenshot from the plugin, it captures the graph as it was before the update while the screen shows the new data. i'm assuming it's because powerpoint caches graphs when the slide shows and it updates the data on screen but not inside the actual presentation. does anybody have an idea how to have powerpoint redraw the graph internally instead of just on screen? or how to capture the screen including the updated graph? here's the code i use:

```
PowerPoint.Slide activeSlide = Wnd.View.Slide;
PowerPoint.Shape pShp = activeSlide.Shapes[1];
Excel.Worksheet xlSH = pShp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets[1];
Excel.Range tRange = xlSH.Cells.get_Range("A1", "B" + (data.options.Length + 1));
foreach (Option o in data.options) 
{
    row++;
    xlSH.Cells.get_Range("A" + row, missing)).FormulaR1C1 = o.key;
    xlSH.Cells.get_Range("B" + row, missing)).FormulaR1C1 = o.value;
}
pShp.Chart.Refresh();

Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new  Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture);
g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
    0, 0,
    bmpScreenCapture.Size);
bmpScreenCapture.Save("C:\\file.jpg");
```

where file then doesn't contain the updated graph but the original one. Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: can i BUMP this post? it's still unresolved

Comment: One of the common issues with other libraries is that in specific cases the chart is not actually updating until you "enter" it and "close" it again. For example with Aspose.Slides this happens when you have formulas in your data. Try to trigger it manually, see if it fixes then if you run the capture code. If that fixes it, just need to write the code to enter the chart again and capture.

Comment: that sounds plausible. but i did some testing and it seems that the data that i can access during a presentation-run is updated as is the graph that's shown on screen. a Refresh() and what not doesn't add anything to that behaviour. looks more and more like powerpoint does something with 3D acceleration that the 'normal' CopyFromScreen totally misses. capturing that looks like an aweful lot of code with complex [dll] calls to boot.. not sure i want to dive into that :(